# Zip file not uploaded to server when post request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, fiddler

The same request works on Fiddler. so the web service is working ok.

When creating http request on Jmeter with same parameters as in fiddler, I get the correct response from server but the file does not appears in site.
It's a simple http post request with zip file.

I have attached the file in "Files upload" in Jmeter with MIME type the same as in Fiddler (application/x-zip-compressed), etc...
but the file get not uploaded while posting from Jmeter.

I dont know what other information you may need, just ask for it and I will try to find it.

this is how the request looks on Fiddler:
[image: this is how the request looks on Fiddler:]

[image: Request on view results tree]

when recording with Jmeter the http request look like the picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting ${FILENAME} under file path in the "Files Upload" section (while leaving its paramter name empty and specifying an encoding) did the trick for me:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should not be "simple" http post request, it has to be [multipart/form-data](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) post request so make double check that you:

1. Either provide full path to the file or drop the file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Use correct "Parameter Name" (should be equal to the [FileUpload object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp) name)
3. Check `Use multipart/form-data for POST` box

[image: JMeter File Upload]

See [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for more information on properly simulating file upload events using JMeter

Comment: Done. The only thing I can think on is the "Parameter Name", i took it from the Fidller request since I dont really have it (you cannot uplod from browser UI\Site only by post request) i saw on Fiddler the following:---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldNameHere"; filename="UME36Pro-5500000-2017-05-17-05-12-23-0006-0000-stat.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed


---------------------------acebdf13572468--, so i take as the "parameter name" the "fieldnamehere"

Comment: Then show "Request" tab of the View Results Tree listener for JMeter

Comment: @Dimitri T - added screenshot of request from view results tree

Comment: So far looks good, can you please enable DEBUG logging under `Options -> Log Level` in JMeter's main menu and either look into the log file yourself or update your question with the content?

Comment: Your `fieldNameHere` parameter name looks utterly suspicious, by the way

Comment: Jmeter log file:                                                   
         https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9GK5P6jft1SUVAxZVJfX2FhV3M

Comment: Added a picture of http request after recording from Jmeter